# Awaiting AE assignment to Under Review?

Tags: peer-review

I have submitted a paper to a very reputed publication of electrical engineering via ScholarOne.The status of my paper changed from "Awaiting AE assignment" to "Under Review" directly. Does it mean that is under the review of editorial office? Could it change from Awaiting AE assignment to Under Review directly without AE being assigned ?

Comment: Could not find answer at above link. My question is, what does change of status directly from "Awaiting AE assignment" to "Under Review" imply ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably just happened quickly. This is peer review - it's not a well oiled machine. Take pride in knowing you passed the first benchmark and keep your fingers crossed R1 and R2 are kind. R3 is always a wildcard.  :)

Comment: Does your answer imply that reviewers have been assigned and it is past the desk reject hurdle ?  Paper is submitted via ScholarOne